# how can we get daily adImpressions for a playlistID using youtube analytics v2 API in python?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have the:

1. content owner id
2. channel id
3. playlistid

Dimension as day

I am currently using https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query to get all other details but I am stuck here.